# Accelerometer (I2C) and Fona Shield (software serial) won't work together

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, shields, softwareserial

I am using a Fona 808 shield with an Arduino Uno and the LSM303 accelerometer. The accelerometer is connected via I2C and the Fona uses software serial.

My project requires the accelerometer to be continuously polled and occasionally talk with the fona. I wrote a program that just used the fona, but once I added the accelerometer code the program would hang a few seconds after comms had been opened with the Fona. I have tested both the accelerometer and the fona shield separately, and they work fine. So, I wrote another smaller (test) program (which is attached below) to find the origin of the program, which I identified to be:

```
fonaSerial->begin(4800);

fona.begin(*fonaSerial);
```

After these lines of code are added, the problem arises. As I said before, this is what I see a few seconds after comms have been opened with the Fona.
http://pasteboard.co/A16708fo3.png

My test program reads the value from the accelerometer, calculates the magnitude of the acceleration and if it's over 20, it prints "Over 20", while also initialising Fona serial.

My question is: Why don't the accelerometer (I2C) and the Fona (Serial) work together and how this be fixed?

This is quite urgent so a quick responses are greatly appreciated!

My Code:

```
#include <Adafruit_FONA.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <My2_Adafruit_LSM303_U.h>
#include <Wire.h>


#define FONA_RX 2
#define FONA_TX 3
#define FONA_RST 4


#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial fonaSS = SoftwareSerial(FONA_TX, FONA_RX);
SoftwareSerial *fonaSerial = &fonaSS;


Adafruit_FONA fona = Adafruit_FONA(FONA_RST);


volatile byte accelMagnitude;

Adafruit_LSM303_Accel_Unified accel = Adafruit_LSM303_Accel_Unified(54321);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

    accel.begin();

    Serial.begin(115200);


    fonaSerial->begin(4800);
    fona.begin(*fonaSerial);

}


void ReadAccel(){

//Get a new accelerometer sensor event
  sensors_event_t event;
 // Serial.println(F("Accel---------"));
  accel.getEvent(&event);

  accelMagnitude = sqrt( sq(event.acceleration.x) + sq(event.acceleration.y) + sq(event.acceleration.z));

}


void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

    ReadAccel();

    if (accelMagnitude > 20){

        while (accelMagnitude > 20){

            Serial.println("waiting");
            ReadAccel();
        }

        Serial.println("Over 20");

    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding some additional Serial.print commands, so you can see where the programs gets stuck.

Comment: The code works fine for about 4 seconds after opening comm with ATs and then it just stops completely.

Comment: How do you know that is stops completely? It could be that the accelerometer is returning false data, and that the arduino code is still running fine. That's why I suggested adding additional Serial.println commands. When debugging some code, I sometimes have a Serial.println between every line of code, so I know exactly where the problem occurs.

Comment: I added Serial.println("Hello");  into the loop. Hello is printed continuously and then stops after 4 seconds.

Comment: Well, there you have narrowed it a bit down. Try adding some more commands and see exactly after which statement is stops. In the mean time try changing `sensors_event_t event;` to `static sensors_event_t event;`. I've got a feeling, that maybe there's a memory issue.

Comment: I added static but nothing changed. I also added Serial.println("Bye"); into the ReadAccel(); function. The last word it prints is hello (which means the program stops in the ReadAccel() function).

Comment: What are you using to power the circuit?

Comment: Also, try adding a small delay in the loop, and see if it now takes more than 4 seconds.

Comment: I am using a 3.7V Lithium Polymer battery to power the circuit. I first added a 100 ms delay and then a 10 ms delay. The 100 ms delay worked for about a minute. The 10 ms produced the same problem as earlier and once I switched back to the 100 ms delay I again got the same problem as earlier.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: I removed the static and tried the delay again. It nows seems to sort of work. Why could this be?

Comment: Too little free RAM? Too little power (e.g. the fona connects to the cell-network after 4 seconds, and required a lot of power to transmit)? Something else?

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!!!! The connection to the cellular network seems to be the problem. I added a 10 sec delay before starting the loop to allow the Fona to connect to the network!

Comment: Glad you got it working. But I'd still try and figure out the exact problem if you can. It might come up later, when you try sending a text-message for example. Maybe adding a large capacitor to Vcc.

Comment: I have the same problem, I'm not using an accelerometer, but a RGB sensor that works via I2C too. I did come to the same solution of waiting a fair amount of time before initializing the I2C, but after a random amount of time it restarts the arduino.

Answer (score 1):

As Gerben suggests, it would not be a good practice to just add a delay and call it a day.

1) Have a large electrolytic capacitor between Vcc and GND as near as you can to the FONA and

2) FONA has `getNetworkStatus();` make a small control loop and query it until you get status 1 or 5, depending on what network are you on.
From FONA's example:

```
if (n == 0) Serial.println(F("Not registered"));
if (n == 1) Serial.println(F("Registered (home)"));
if (n == 2) Serial.println(F("Not registered (searching)"));
if (n == 3) Serial.println(F("Denied"));
if (n == 4) Serial.println(F("Unknown"));
if (n == 5) Serial.println(F("Registered roaming"));
```

And then proceed with the rest of your code. You can make additional checks for signal quality with `getRSSI();`